# How can I make this card with ngFor like in this picture, with automatic adjust column in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

here's my code

```html
<div class="row px-5 py-4">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let row of data; let i = index">
    <div class="card px-4 py-4 mb-3" style="height: 400px">
      <div>
        <app-static-html [widget]="row" *ngIf="isStaticContent(row)"></app-static-html>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: 1]

can you help me for this

Appreciate your help

Comment: You should post some relevant code. Besides, you can easily achieve it using [grid-template-areas](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and set `flex-basis:100%` on every 4th card.

```css
#zone { 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
}

.card:nth-child(4n) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="zone">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you gave a reason why you unaccepted my answer 5 weeks later. My snippet clearly demonstrates the necessary CSS to reproduce the screenshot you posted. If there was a problem, a simple conversation could have worked it out.